# Configure destinationsViewController based on selectedRowAtIndexPath

Tags: swift, uitableview, segue

I got no code because im very confused. I got a UITableView, the user can create cells by naming. The cells all segue to the same UITableViewController, so far i segue the cell.textlabel?.text to the next UIViewController so they differentiates based on the name. On the destinationViewController i want the user to be able to create a deck of flashCards. These decks of flashCards should off course be connected to their respective UITableViewCell. Anyone know how you achieve such behaviour? Or a place were i can ask a question as such.

App example.

UITableViewCell (cell.textlabel?.text = DogsBreeds) ->(Segue)-> UIViewController (Containing the users customised deck of dogflashCards)

UITableViewCell (cell.textlabel?.text = HorseBreeds)->(Segue)-> UIViewController (Containing the users customised deck of horseFlashCards)